# Does serving large files block other connections from being served in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

In article I've just read was mentioned that that's not recommended to return big amount of data (like pictures) through node.js because in event loop all following users would have to wait until this 'picture' (or something else) would be transported. Is this true?

Comment: Got a reference to that article?

Comment: Aha. I've reread it, so I got an idea wrong - the author meant only "heavy" calculations. And that's logic enough.

Comment: Just FYI, by heavy calculations, they mean really heavy calculations (converting videos, recalculating huge maps of millions of tiles etc) and in general, you will never notice the effect. Luckily, you can easily write parts that need extreme calculations in C and run them via command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is only true if you're not using node.js properly.  If you're correctly creating your listener, you shouldn't end up serializing on this.